# Is it possible to place a file in /target before install starts, using a preseed?

Tags: system-installation, preseed, passwd-file

I'm using a preseed to install my system. However, I'd like to place existing passwd and group files in /target/etc, after partitioning, but before the install starts. Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't work what you want. passwd will be overwritten during install. What you need to do is setup the users in your kickstart so passwd will be created by the system.

Comment: Looking at the base-passwd.preinst file -
`if [ ! -e /etc/passwd ]`
So it looks like if I place my passwd file after partitioning, it won't get clobbered by the installer. I just need to figure out **where** in the preseed to do that.

Comment: I don't think I ever got it to work :-P Do post an answer when you do >:-D

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify what I want to accomplish - I have a group of existing accounts in an existing network directory. I want to make sure that same UIDs/GIDs get used on my Ubuntu installs. Therefore, I'd like to place an existing passwd and group file in /target/etc before the install kicks off. That way, installed files get the correct ownership. Any suggestions on how to do this?